# How to position a label relative to another label

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have  a `UITableView` with custom cells. Inside each cell I have two `UILabels` - **message** and **type**. The size message label is varying and the type label should come below the message label.
Since the size of message label is varying. How can I position the y coordinate of the type label ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MARGIN 5
typeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, messagelabel.frame.size.height + messageLabel.frame.origin.y + MARGIN ,
                             w , h);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if your have already set the frame for type label and want the same height width and  x position

```
CGRect frame=type_label.frame;
frame.origin.y=messagelabel.frame.origin.y + messagelabel.frame.size.height + some_gap_if_you_want;
type_label.frame=frame;
```

or if you havnt set the frame try this

```
type_label.frame=CGRectMake(x,messagelabel.frame.origin.y + messagelabel.frame.size.height + some_gap_if_you_want,width,height);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(messagelabel.frame),
                             CGRectGetMaxY(messagelabel.frame)+space,
                             w, h)
```

I find this much more readable ;)